# IPIP tunnel packets are not send

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, tunnel

I have a VPS with an external IP say `40.40.40.40` and trying to create IPIP tunnel to it. Here is what I tried:

```
#create interface megatun0 to tunnel traffic through the host 40.40.40.40.
sudo ip tunnel add megatun0 mode ipip remote 40.40.40.40 local 192.168.15.1

#set local address of the megatun0 interface
sudo ip address add 192.168.15.2 dev megatun0

#turn it on
sudo ip link set dev megatun0 up

#add a route to the routing table
sudo ip route add 192.168.15.0/24 dev megatun0
```

So I expect the IP packets routed through `192.168.15.0/24 dev megatun0 scope link` are redirected to the `40.40.40.40` via IP tunnel. But when doing `ping 192.168.15.1` and capturing `tcpdump` on the laptop as follows:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -vv -n proto \\icmp
```

I don't even see `ICMP` packets are being sent to the VPS. But what I do see is that `TX errors` on the `megatun0` interface are getting increased:

```
megatun0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet 192.168.15.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.15.2
        inet6 fe80::5efe:c0a8:f01  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 115  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 115  collisions 0
```

I expected that IPIP tunnel packets are received on the VPS side and just dropped because it's not known what to do with them. But they aren't even sent.

What did I do wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the documentation. The tunnel's `remote` and `local` parameters should be IP addresses accessible from both sides. And besides the `local` should be exactly the address of some network interface. Here is what `man ip-tunnel` mentions regarding `local`:

```
local ADDRESS
                 set the fixed local address for tunneled packets.
                 It must be an address on another interface of this
                 host.
```

So providing that my laptop's external IP attached to `eth0` is `50.50.50.50` here is the correct tunnel setup:

```
sudo ip tunnel add megatun0 mode ipip remote 40.40.40.40 local 50.50.50.50
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).